# Running a python script with HTML button

Tags: python, html

How can I call a python script when the button is html file is clicked?
I am trying to change the language of the website by clicking the button. This is what I have done so far, but I am getting an error when I hit the button "page not found" and "The current URL, foo, didn't match any of these." What am I doing wrong

**login.html**

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
<input type="submit" name = "first_button" value="French">
<input type="submit" name = "second_button" value="Spanish">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
from app import foo

def get_language_from_client(request):   
new_lang= foo()
if new_lang=="fr":
    client_lang="fr"
else:
    client_lang = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
print "client_lang:", client_lang
if "en" in client_lang:
    return 0
elif "nl" in client_lang:
    return 1
elif "fr" in client_lang:
    return 2
elif "pl" in client_lang:
    return 3
elif "ru" in client_lang:
    return 4
else:
    print "Unknown language code:", client_lang
    return 2
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return "fr"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**My directory structure looks like**

```
scriboxapp
-templates
  -login.html
-views.py
-app.py
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) for this.

Here's an example of what you can do:

`index.html`:

```
<form action="/foo" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="French">
</form>
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    '''execute whatever code you want when the button gets clicked here'''
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When you run your `app.py` file and navigate to the URL where the Flask webserver is running, which in this case is localhost, you will be presented with the `index.html` file.

In the above example, you can see that the button containing the value `French` will execute your `/foo` route. Your function with the proper route decorator `/foo` is where you can execute your desired code.

To get this working, your directory structure should look something like this:

```
- app
    - templates
        - index.html
    - app.py
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for responding quickly. I am not familiar with directory structure. How can I access it?

Comment: @SamraMemon By directory structure I mean the folder where your project is. Create a folder called `app`, then inside a file called `app.py` and a folder called `templates`. `index.html` goes inside `templates`.

Comment: I have edited my question as a response to your answer. I dont know how to write code in comments.

Comment: @SamraMemon sorry I forgot to include that your foo route needs to accept the proper HTTP requests. You can look at the Flask docs to see where to put them in the decorator :)

Comment: Can you please give me a tiny hint? I went through the docs but nothing is working unfortunately.